# Gmail delegation access

Tags: google-api, gmail-api

I have a software in C# where I use Google C# SDK and my admin user access token has the gmail.readonly
scope.
When trying to make queries for the Gmail messages , I encounterd an issue where I can make a request only for the admin user which is authenticatd and for other organization user I'm getting the 403 forbidden error which says that delegation is not allowed for my admin user to request on behalf of others.

So I understood that each end user needs to give access (delegation) to the admin user to read the gmail messages on behalf of the end user and so I did.

But somehow I still get the 403 forbiddan error even tough I've granted an acess to my admin user account via gmail settings of the another user.

Is there anything missing ?

Here is my C# code :

foreach (var user in users)
{
try
{
m_logger.Debug($"{Prefix_logger} Adding {user.PrimaryEmail} to email polling batch query...");
// Create a Gmail API request for querying messages for a specific user
var request = service.Users.Messages.List(user.PrimaryEmail);

```
                    string nextPageToken = null;
       
                    request.Q = $"after:{from:yyyy/MM/dd}";
                    request.MaxResults = 100;
                    request.PageToken = nextPageToken;
```

// At this point it fails on another user except the admin.
var g = await request.ExecuteAsync();

```
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    if (e.Message.Contains($"Delegation denied for {adminToken.Upn}"))
                        m_logger.Error($"{Prefix_logger} User {user.PrimaryEmail} didn't share email box with admin");
                    else
                        m_logger.Error($"{Prefix_logger} Error : {e}");
                }

            }
```

I tried to make requests to gmail on behalf of another user which granted me the access and I was expecting to get success response while getting 403 forbidden